# What is the *right* way to seed random number generation in a python multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pool, random-seed

I am using `Pool.map()` in the `multiprocessing` package on an embarrassingly parallel project. I want to seed the numpy random number generator once for each worker (not once per function call). My understanding from some past answers is that one should use the initializer parameter to seed each worker. However, when I pass `numpy.random.seed`, I get very poor seeding--all threads generate mostly the same random numbers, but not all.

There have been some changes to the way random numbers work in numpy so perhaps some of those answers are out of date. Take a look at this minimal example that illustrates the issue:

```py
import multiprocessing                                                              
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                    
def my_fun(_):                                  
    return rng.uniform()                                                                                             
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, initializer=np.random.seed) as pool:
        my_list = pool.map(my_fun, range(40))  
    print(f"Number of unique values: {len(set(my_list))}")
```

I would expect `my_list` to contain exactly 40 distinct values if seeding works or exactly 10 if it does not. But it tends to be more like 12-15. Is there a different best-practice for seeding these workers? Remember, I do not want to add any code to `my_fun()` because it will be called a large number of times by each worker. I just want each worker to start from a different place, so workers will be independent.

I do not require reproducibility for this project, but it would be nice if the solution did provide it. Python 3.10.5 on linux.

Comment: How does this work if you create the `rng` object in your "main" function, and do not pass it to the function `my_fun`, yet use it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  Try this instead:

```
import multiprocessing                                                              
import numpy as np

def init():
    global rng
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
                                                                                    
def my_fun(_):                                  
    return rng.uniform()                                                                                             
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, initializer=init) as pool:
        my_list = pool.map(my_fun, range(40))  
    print(f"Number of unique values: {len(set(my_list))}")
```

The recommendation is that instead of using seeding, you should create a new instance of the generator instead.  Here we're creating one new, freshly seed generator for each pool.

For reproducible results, add code to `init()` to pickle each new generator or print its state:

```
print(rng.__getstate__())
```

The output is sufficient to reconstructor the generator state.  It looks like this:

```
{'bit_generator': 'PCG64',
 'state': 
     {'state': 319129345033546980483845008489532042435,
      'inc': 198751095538548372906400916761105570237},
 'has_uint32': 0,
 'uinteger': 0}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. I will leave the question open for a little bit in case there are other opinions on the "best practice" part of the question. Sure do appreciate your help.

Comment: @famsy That wasn't an opinion. It was taken directly from the numpy docs, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html : "The best practice is to not reseed a BitGenerator, rather to recreate a new one. This method is here for legacy reasons. This example demonstrates best practice."

Comment: Oh, I wasn't referring to that aspect of your answer, nor was I seeking to reframe your answer as an opinion--sorry if it sounded that way. Sometimes here on SO you get a variety of suggestions, some of which are a wholesale departure from the poster's original approach. I wanted to leave at least a few hours in case that might be the case here.

Comment: In this code, is the initial state of `rng` different for every process which is spawned by `pool.map()`?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, each process gets a different initial state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have a better answer than Raymond, but I was evidently unfamiliar with the rather significant changes to numpy's random module so I did some investigation to understand it further.

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#quick-start), Numpy now discourages using the module constant generator: `mtrand.RandomState` in favor of explicitly creating your own `Generator` instance via `default_rng()`. This encourages programmers to be deliberate about randomness particularly for security (or repeatability). In your code you seem to mix attempting to use the old style and new style of the `numpy.random` module. This is the actual error, for which Raymond posted the solution: `np.random.seed` does not set the seed for `rng`, it sets the seed for `np.random.mtrand.RandomState`. You are then using the same `rng` for each child process (copied via fork) which does not get updated by `np.random.seed`. On a side note, I would also point out that relying on fork to copy `rng` so it is available in `my_fun` only works with fork, and won't work on Windows or MacOS where spawn is used. Raymond's solution also solves this problem, as `rng` is explicitly created in the child after fork/spawn.

Finally, you say you have an "embarrassingly parallel" scenario, and according to the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/upgrading-pcg64.html#upgrading-pcg64), there may be instances where you want to use a different `BitGenerator` to the standard PCG-64 generator (the math is a bit over my head though):

```
rng = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64DXSM())
#or if you want to know for sure you're using the best available seed source:
rng = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64DXSM(secrets.randbits(128)))
```